# Particle slider mobile resize not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, slider, particles

I am using this particle slider on my page: http://particleslider.com/

It works good, but on mobile devices it is not resizing. It just centers in the middle of the screen depending on the device size. Particle slider uses image URI to convert an image into particles. If the image width is larger than the phone width, it won't scale down - it overlaps horizontally like this:

[image]

How can I make it scale down so the entire image can be shown, irrelevant of device width?

Comment: It seems to work on the Particle website.  Did you mess with the width or height of the image that might be conflicting?  Do you have an example of your CSS, HTML and JS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work on the Particle website.  Did you mess with the width or height of the image that might be conflicting?  Do you have an example of your CSS, HTML and JS? 
In their CSS, they are setting the outside container of the element does not have a width but a max-width of 95% in the CSS. 
Did you set a width in the JS as an option?

According to their documentation that sets a static width. Default is 800.

```
    // Create a 100px wide ParticleSlider.
  var ps = new ParticleSlider({
    width: 100
  });
```

Most likely you could use CSS to fix your issue.
First, if you are, don't put a width in the ParticleSlider() as an option.
Second, force the max-width of the container element of your slider to be something like 95%.

Their CSS shows something like this for theirs

```
#particle-slider {
width: 41.8em;
height: 26.3em;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you have code, please post it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using [this](http://codepen.io/Zaku/pen/EDaun) example from codepen. My code is pretty much the same as there, I haven't changed anything except the image. Maybe it's because I have added a bigger image? Also, I tried giving the width of 100 and removing the width, and it didn't work. Also tried adding that css, and didn't work.